# How to allow some specifics URLs and rest of others would be redirect to maintenance page

Tags: .htaccess

I have an issue on my htaccess file..

http://www.example.com/customer/contract/download
http://www.example.come/customer/contract/upload

These above urls should work and rest of other urls should redirect to maintenance.html.

How can i defined these cases on my htaccess file ??

Here is my htaccess code..

```
RewriteEngine on
IndexIgnore *

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|redirigir\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/maintenance.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have two lines that capture all URLs and have the `[L] last` flag. Your second `RewriteRule`acts only on the exceptions configured in the first `RewriteCond`. You need to change like this in order to get your second RewriteRule come into play:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|redirigir\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/maintenance.html [L]
```

Then add your exception URLs to the.htaccess file.

If they are valid directories, you simply add a line to exclude *all* directories. You need to add the [OR] flag, which means that either RewriteCond has to be true. Without this flag, the rule matches only when both conditions apply.

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|redirigir\.php) [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/maintenance.html [L]
```

If they are rewritten through the first rewrite rule, you must add another condition on the first rule:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|redirigir\.php)
RewriteCond $1 customer/contract/(download|upload)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/maintenance.html [L]
```

Here the first rule will only match your special URLs, and the second rule will match everything else.

Comment: I m using route system in my project in which urls look like this..     $route['contrato/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)'] = 'generar_contrato/contrato/$1/$2/0/$3';
$route['contrato/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)'] = 'generar_contrato/contrato/$1/$2/$3/$4';

Answer (score 0):

Following rule should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine on
IndexIgnore *

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|redirigir\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|images|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|redirigir\.php|customer)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/maintenance.html [L]
```